# Read Text file and Create a Python Dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a text file as mentioned below:

```
KEY,NAME,RANK,BOOKNAME,SCORE,AUTHER
123,ABCD,500,FREEDOM1,15200,PXYZ
133,EFGH,400,FREEDOM2,15300.5,XTYZ
nan,SYGH,700,FREEDOM3,15400,RYYZ
143,LKMN,800,FREEDOM4,15500.5,XYCZ
```

I want read this text file and create a nested dictionary which will be used in my subsequent program.

```
dict = {
123:{'NAME':'ABCD','RANK':500,'BOOKNAME':'FREEDOM1', 'SCORE':15200, 'AUTHER':'PXYZ'},
133:{'NAME':'EFGH','RANK':400,'BOOKNAME':'FREEDOM2', 'SCORE':15300.5, 'AUTHER':'XTYZ'},
143:{'NAME':'LKMN','RANK':800,'BOOKNAME':'FREEDOM4', 'SCORE':15500.5, 'AUTHER':'XYCZ'}
}
```

Note: Code should remove the rows with 'nan' KEY values

Comment: usually stackoverflow works best if you have made an effort to solve this yourself first, and share that effort with us

Comment: please add the code that you have written so far

Comment: Sir, I am very new to Python. I am unable to split the column name. kindly help.

Comment: Looks like a [`csv.DictReader`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.DictReader) will be useful.

Comment: What do you mean by "split the column name"? Please tell us the step where you are stuck: reading the file, reading the first row, splitting that row into column names (is this what you mean?), reading the other rows, splitting those rows into values, creating the nested dictionary, or something else? If your problem is splitting the first row, show us your code before that point and as much as possible after that point.

Comment: Yea I am having problem with reading the first row, splitting that row into column names.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `csv.DictReader` to create a list of OrderedDicts from your data file. Then you can rearrange and transform your data to make the nested dictionary to meet your requirements. Here is an example using dictionary comprehension.

```
import csv

with open('text.csv') as f:
    reader = csv.DictReader(f)
    result = {
        int(d['KEY']):{k: int(v) if v.isdigit() else v for k, v in d.items() if k != 'KEY'}
        for d in reader if d['KEY'].isdigit()}
    print(result)
```

EDIT: If all you need is the `string` values as posted in Tanmay's solution then this does the same with a lot less code.

```
import csv
from pprint import pprint

with open('text.csv') as f:
    results = {d.pop('KEY'): dict(d) for d in csv.DictReader(f)}
pprint(results)
```

EDIT 2: casting values

```
import csv
from pprint import pprint
import re


def cast_dict(d: dict):
    def cast_value(value: str):
        if value.isdigit():
            return int(value)
        elif re.match(r'^\d+\.\d+$', value):
            return float(value)
        return value
    return {k: cast_value(v) for k, v in d.items()}


with open('text.csv') as f:
    results = {int(d.pop('KEY')): cast_dict(d) for d in csv.DictReader(f) if d.get['KEY'].isdigit()}
```

pprint(results)
    pprint(results)

Comment: Thanks Sir, This is working.

Comment: I don't have enough rep points to comment on Tanmay's solution, so I'll comment here... While it uses some simpler logic it is what most would be considered as "unpythonic". Also it doesn't meet your design conditions because it doesn't convert string digits to ints. If all you need is string then the "pythonic" solution is even easier. See the edit in the above answer.

Comment: Sir, Your solution best suite my condition. But I am now facing problem with few rows where I have floats which is also marked as string. I want Int() as integer and float() as float.  Can you help me on this.

Comment: You need to supply some sample data...

Comment: Sample Data where I have few Score as float: KEY,NAME,RANK,BOOKNAME,SCORE,AUTHER
123,ABCD,500,FREEDOM1,15200,PXYZ
133,EFGH,400,FREEDOM2,15300.5,XTYZ
nan,SYGH,700,FREEDOM3,15400,RYYZ
143,LKMN,800,FREEDOM4,15500.5,XYCZ

Comment: @nicholishen I am converting string to int .. and I thought op doesn't know much ..that why I tried to break down solution in simple manner and its true it can be optimized further. btw your solution looks nice and obviously if there is a package for something we want use it be lazyy :) that's the identity of smart person... :)

Comment: @nicholishen sorry I thought you were talking about key

Comment: @Tanmayjain I see you've edited your answer after I posted the comment... using verbose unpythonic algorithms doesn't make one to be not lazy. Conversely, clean, beautiful, idiomatic python is not only easier to read, but also runs more efficiently.

Comment: @nicholishen I was not being sarcastic sorry you misunderstood.. I am lazy myself.

Comment: @Pravat See edit #2

Comment: @nicholishen https://pasteboard.co/HzMmIh5.png fix your edit 2 it's adding 'nan' key

Comment: Hi Sir, Now the Float problem got resolved. But KEY column is appearing as string  and also repeated again inside nested dict. Your 1st solution was absolutely right but SCORE Column float values are considered as string. Can you please edit the first code to detect float as float in SCORE Column.

Comment: @Pravat Easy fix, modify the comprehension: results = {int(d.pop('KEY')): cast_dict(d) for d in csv.DictReader(f) if d['KEY'].isdigit()}

Comment: Wow !! Many Thanks. Problem Resolved @nicholishen

Comment: @Tanmayjain You forgot to close your file. Also, both of our solutions run at the same efficiency. I'm not sure where you got your numbers from... https://repl.it/repls/MushyPrevailingJumpthreading

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`csv`](https://kite.com/python/docs/csv) module like this. If you need to check if KEY value is number, create corresponding function:

```
import csv

def is_float(s):
    try:
        float(s)
    except ValueError:
        return  False
    return True


with open('input.csv') as f:
    reader = csv.DictReader(f)
    rows = list(dict(a) for a in iter(reader) if is_float(a['KEY']))

print(rows)
```

Answer (score 0):

things that you will need to do to achieve your goal are

first you need to how to open file(assuming its .txt file containing comma separated values)

```
filename = "csv_data.txt"
file = open(filename, "r") #opening in read mode
line_list = []
for line in file:
   print(line) #line_list.append(line.strip().split(','))
```

then you would want to split string(*line*) using ',' as delimiters for that you would have to do `line.split(',')` this will give you list.

```
line_list[0]
```

here you will find list of all the strings in line 1 of your text file.

okay I have decided to add code but please **don't copy paste** try to understand it google or go to python docs look what each inbuilt function do.

```
from collections import defaultdict

filename = "csv_data.txt"
file = open(filename, "r") #opening in read mode
line_list = []
output_dict = defaultdict(dict) #read about defualtdict vs dict

for line in file:
    #print(line,end='')
    line_list.append(line.strip().split(','))


key_names = line_list[0] #remember firstline in our file contains name of keys

#read about slicing
for line in line_list[1:]:
    #print(line)
    this_key = line[0]
    if this_key == 'nan':
        continue #we don't want to add this to our dict

    else:
        this_key = int(this_key)
        output_dict[this_key]= defaultdict(dict)

        # read about enumerate
        for i,word in enumerate(line[1:], start = 1):

            this_key_dict =  output_dict[this_key]   
            if key_names[i] == 'SCORE' or key_names[i] == 'RANK':
                try:
                   word = int(word)

                except ValueError:
                   word = float(word)  

            this_key_dict[key_names[i]] = word




def nice_print(dict_d):

    for i,v in dict_d.items():
        print(i,v)


nice_print(output_dict)


>>> word = '7.8'
>>> float(word) if '.' in  word else int(word)
7.8
>>> word = '7'
>>> float(word) if '.' in  word else int(word)
7
>>>
```

Comment: Thanks Sir. Understood the Logic.

Comment: @Pravat if you were having problem with float then now it should work btw you should have mentioned that key can be float

Comment: No Sir, KEY and RANK are int. But SCORE can be float.

Comment: ohh sorry didn't pay attention